# How to validate JSON @RequestBody using org.springframework.validation.Validator in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: json, spring, validation, spring-webflux, spring-validator

I am trying to validate JSON @RequestBody using org.springframework.validation.Validator in Spring WebFlux, but I am getting 'Internal Server Error' with following message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve argument 1 of type 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult' on public reactor.core.publisher.Mono ....
```

Validator Class:

```
@Component
public class GreetingValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        return GreetingSchema.class.equals(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "content", "content.empty", "Content is required");
        GreetingSchema greeting = (GreetingSchema) obj;
    }

}
```

REST Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingValidator validator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public GreetingSchema get() {
        return new GreetingSchema("Hello, World!");
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public Mono post(@Validated @RequestBody GreetingSchema body, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return Mono.just(result.getFieldErrors());
        }
        return Mono.just("valid");
    }
}
```

When I tried after removing @RequestBody annotation from post method as follows

```
public Mono post(@Validated GreetingSchema body, BindingResult result)
```

then it's running without 'Internal Server Error', but not able to validate JSON @RequestBody.

```
{"content": "Hello, Xyz!"}
```

Comment: I am using spring-boot RC1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't configure the WebDataBinder.
 
My code:
controller is like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/url")
public Mono<Result> method(@RequestBody @Validated Message message) {
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //do sth
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return Mono.just(Result.withData(time2 - time1));
}
```

and class Message is like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Message implements Serializable {
    private String content;

    @Range(min = 1,max = 3)
    private int length;

    @NotNull
    private String publisher;
}
```